# C code under performance on Intel Xeon E5-2650

Tags: c, openmp, vectorization, intel, hpc

I have a c code (Open MP parallelized) that takes more than twice as much time to run on an Intel Xeon E5-2650 node (with all 16 cores) as it takes on a desktop with intel i 7 processor. With standard benchmark cases my compute node gives satisfactory performance. I realize this has something to do with the efficiency of my code, to run on modern processors. Could someone please direct me to the aspects of the code that I can improve on? I have come accross issues like vectorization, however I have not been able to find a neat step by step tutorial or document on such things. 
About the code:

The code is a simulation-particles interacting with each other. After identifying neighborhoods, they interact, compute and store data. The particles are an array of structs. An example interaction function looks like this.

```
static void interact(particleData *pdata, int a, int b, interactParams params)
{

  int i;
  double rdotdwdx = 0.0, vdotr =0.0;
  for(i=0;i<dim;i++){
    rdotdwdx += (&params.xr.x)[i]*(&params.dwdx.x)[i];
    vdotr += (&params.vr.x)[i]*(&params.xr.x)[i];
  }
  double Fab = vdotr/(params.rdotr + 0.0001*params.h*params.h);
  double acc;

  for(i = 0; i < dim; i++){

    acc = 8.*(((pdata[a].eta/pdata[a].rho)+(pdata[b].eta/pdata[b].rho)) /(pdata[a].rho+pdata[b].rho))*Fab*(&params.dwdx.x)[i];
    (&pdata[a].acc.x)[i] +=  acc*pdata[b].mass;
    (&pdata[b].acc.x)[i] += -acc*pdata[a].mass;
    }
  }
}
```

Here pdata is an array of struct. acc is a member of pdata[i] and is has members x, y and z. The struct pdata has many other data members too. The members of data param involves math functions like pow. 
The above posted code is one of the parts that shows up in my profiler as consuming maximum time.

The compiler I used in both machines is gcc.

Thank you. I appreciate your patience

Comment: More cores and more threads does not automatically mean better performance. First of all, there's more locking between the threads, then there might be caching problems, as well as possible latencies due to more threads being dispatched.

Comment: You're not going to get much advice without posting your code.

Comment: "Could someone please direct me to the aspects of the code that I can improve on?" How would that even be possible without seeing your code?

Comment: If you are looking for a resource on vectorization/optimization for a Xeon processor, that is off topic.  If you have a section of your code that you can pinpoint as causing a performance issue (try profiling) then people can offer some concrete advice.

Comment: I have edited and added a part of the code. I am basically looking for some guidance, a book, a reference or something that helps me attack systematically, the possible performance weakpoints. I really appreciate your patience.

Comment: It's good you added some code but it's not sufficient. What sections of your code are you parallelizing? Do you get the correct result with and without OpenMP? What exactly is your i7 desktop processor? Your E5-2650 does not have 16 cores, it has 8 cores and 16 hyper threads. Can you add this information to your question?

Answer (score 1):

The example code appears to be using an array of structs, which is a classic under-performing motif for N-body simulations, among other things.  You should read up on AoS-to-SoA transformations, where SoA is struct-of-arrays and is almost always the right way to compute what I think you are trying to compute.

In addition to using the AoS motif, your loop is full of code with large amounts of indirection.  You should look up the assembly for `(&pdata[a].acc.x)[i]` and see exactly how many instructions it takes just to assign to this quantity.

If there are loop invariants, you should pull them out of your loop and potentially replace these highly indirect access with ones using a single pointer and then iterating through the data using that pointer.  I don't know how easy that is to do or how well it will work, but that's where I'd start if I were you.

There are a number of Google hits for "AoS-to-SoA transformations"; among them is https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/memory-layout-transformations, which seems particularly relevant to your case.